# Using Interfaces with method signatures

Tags: java

The following is part of a skeleton code I've been given to work on, and implement new methods and classes etc.

```
public interface Character {
  Move update(int location, List<Move> list);
}
```

I've recently started using java, I understand that to use any of this I have create a class which "implements" this interface, for example

```
public class MyCharacter implements Character {
    ....
}
```

But I was just wondering how exactly I use "update"? And what exactly is it?

Comment: Apologies, but even if it was just the syntax for calling update? I only read that it was called a method signature but I can't find anywhere what that means?

Comment: No need for sorry.. It's fine. BTW, as per Java naming convention, a class name should start with upper case letter. `MyCharacter` instead of `myCharacter`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you implement an interface in one of your class, the important thing is to provide the code for the `update` method. Your implementation may also use that method for its own purposes, but the primary goal is to implement it.

Syntactically this means adding a definition for a public method with an identical signature, like this:

```
public class myCharacter implements Character {
    public Move update(int location, List<Move> list) {
         // Your implementation goes here
         // Perhaps you want to return list.get(location)?
    }
}
```

The logic for the implementation is up to you: you need to write the code that performs the "update" according to `myCharacter` behavior specification, and returns the corresponding `Move` object.

Comment: Exactly the answer I was after. Thanks so much!